# Get column by name from a <select> with GAS in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a GAS powered dependent dropdown, which I have now come very close to achieving with the help from stackoverflow, thanks to all.

But I have come to a point where there is a lack of documentation? Or answer to. 
I am trying to get a specific column by name, by that I find the column that has the header/top row value of a certain input. In this case it's a dropdown running on an HTML page, that speaks with GAS.

Most of the script works just fine, it's the building what I call topics in the buttom of the HTML and the Code.gs that is causing me some trouble. Right now it's not getting the columns in anyway, but that's because I haven't found a way of doing it yet. The parts that are not working right now are: `function buildTopicsList(rowsName)` in the HTML and the `function getTopics(subCategories,categories)` in Code.gs

Here I want to get all the rows in a column with a "header" selected from a dropdown in the html.

The full HTML looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<div>
<select id="categories" onchange="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildSubCategoriesList)
.getSubCategories(this.value)">
<option>Loading...</option>    
</select>

<select id="subCategories" onchange="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTopicsList)
 .getTopics(this.value)">
  <option>Loading...</option>    
</select>

<select id="topics">
  <option>Loading...</option>    
</select>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildCategoriesList).getCategories();
});

function buildCategoriesList(sheetsName) {
var list = $('#categories');
list.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < sheetsName.length; i++) {
list.append('<option value="' + sheetsName[i] + '">' + sheetsName[i] + '</option>');
}
list.trigger("change");
}

function buildSubCategoriesList(columnsName) {
console.log(columnsName);
var list = $('#subCategories');
list.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < columnsName.length; i++) {
list.append('<option value="' + columnsName[i] + '">' + columnsName[i] + '</option>');
}
list.trigger("change");
}

function buildTopicsList(rowsName) {
console.log(rowsName);
var list = $('#topics');
list.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < rowsName.length; i++) {
list.append('<option value="' + rowsName[i] + '">' + rowsName[i] + '</option>');
}
}

</script>
```

and the code:

**Code.gs**

```
var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BK5urtTzqZ2kc89ZnbeMSIm2-bt4KLNTQghsxn0cXBI");

function doGet(request) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getCategories(){
var sheetsName = [];
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for( var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ ){
sheetsName.push( sheets[i].getName() )
}
return sheetsName;
}

function getSubCategories(categories){
var columnsName = [];
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(categories);
var subRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
var columns = subRange.getValues()[0]; 

for( var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++ ){
columnsName.push( columns[i] )
}
return columnsName;
}

// this here is not working:
function getTopics(subCategories,categories){
var rowsName = [];

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(categories);
var topRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
var rows = topRange.getValues()[0]; 

for( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ){
rowsName.push( rows[i] )
}
 return rowsName;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any `Logger.log('some text: ' + aVariableName);` statements in your code.  If you aren't familiar with troubleshooting options, one of the best things you can do is take 5 minutes to read the troubleshooting guide.  [Google Documentation - Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: I see that you just changed the variable `columnsName` to `rowsName` in the `getTopics()` function.  Are you getting an error in the "Execution Transcript"?  If so, what is it?  What line of code is giving you an error?

Comment: It's not giving me any error messages, the dropdown simply isn't loading any of the values listed in the desired column, because I am not getting the column in anyway. Which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Right before this line `return rowsName;` put in a `Logger.log('rowsName: ' + rowsName);` statement, run the function and then VIEW the LOGS.  Are there values in the `rowsName` variable?

Comment: The log doesn't seem to be logging anything? I could try alerting instead? When I am in the HTML?

Comment: See my updated answer.  `this.value` is being passed to `subCategories` as the first parameter being received.  There is no second parameter being passed, which would end up in the `categories` argument.  The `categories` argument will always be empty.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, really glad for the help. but my script is working here: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzWi3JymieWMAGVLQVl2xEXCd_eo85hWercHAFkNrqH5dkvWWQd/exec But I am not getting the last value.

Comment: These are the sheet names in your sheet:  **Vegetables, Fruits, Countries**  You don't have a sheet named "Cucumber".  You can't get a sheet that doesn't exist.  That's why the 3rd drop down isn't getting any values.

Comment: I am not trying to get a sheet, I am trying to get the index of the the column where cucumber is, so that I can get the values listed in that column, I have a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BK5urtTzqZ2kc89ZnbeMSIm2-bt4KLNTQghsxn0cXBI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91906/discussion-between-william-larsen-bang-and-sandy-good).

Answer (score 0):

The server function `getTopics(subCategories,categories)` is being called by `onchange` attribute:

```
onchange="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTopicsList)
```

.getTopics(this.value)"

`this.value` is being passed to the `getTopics(subCategories,categories)` function.  But the `getTopics(subCategories,categories)` function accepts two parameters, not one.  And the first parameter, `subCategories` is never being used in the code.  That's why you aren't getting anything.  Put in a `Logger.log('categories: ' + categories);` statement at the top of the `getTopics(subCategories,categories)` function, and I'll bet that it shows nothing.

As a "side note".  The `doGet()` function is using the `createTemplateFromFile()` method, but there are no scriptlets in your **index.html** file.  The **index.html** file is *not* a template.  If you were using a template, you wouldn't need to run some of the browser code when the html loads.  I'm not saying that it's better to use the scriptlets, or suggesting you do that.  But I just wanted you to know what is happening and what your options are.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase, most of the script is working fine, all I need right now is to get the column number of a value in the chosen row. - So whatever value is selected in my dropdown, will be the value too look for in the spreadsheet, and find the column number. But thanks for the tip!